# Can anyone help me create an iframe which will disallow top-level-navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Scenario - I've an iframe that is from site.abc.com and I want to put the iframe on site.xyz.com. The iframe from site.abc.com requires access to headers of site.xyz.com to render the contents within the iframe, however if I am sandboxing the iframe then the iframe becomes like a lock down container and contents within iframe is not rendering.

If I am allowing sandbox attributes with "allow-scripts" and "allow-top-level-navigation" then the iframe is working again.

In my knowledge (correct me if I am wrong). No matter how many nested iframe be it running on the page site.xyz.com, when we are passing "allow-top-level-navigation" I believe that the iframe fetches the final page's browser url i.e. site.xyz.com using a url query string parameter "top"

I am keen to block this parameter so that the contents within iframe does not get access to top-level-navigation url at the same time I want to ensure that contents within iframe get access to "top-level-navigation" using custom http headers or any other similar solution that we can inject inside the iframe 
therefore making the contents within iframe believe that its accessing headers and top level data of site.xyz.com

I am also keen to know how can I restrict any cookies dropped or set by the contents within the iframe remains confined within iframe and does not get dropped into the page where we are running the iframe.

I am looking for a solution where I can make this iframe a complete isolated and secure container while providing all the accurate information of the header and http requests relayed inside the iframe so that the contents within iframe does not have any issue in accessing the real-time http headers within iframe to render inside the iframe. I want the content's of the iframe's execution to be limited within and inside of the iframe only.

Kindly help me with sample or prototype iframe codes which I can use for testing. If anyone can help me with the complete solution, I'll be really grateful to him